# How can I find out energy density from battery (current) capacity, in amperes-hour [Ah] and battery voltage, in volts [V]

Tags: battery-charging, energy

I want to know the energy density of the battery.

I only have details from [here](https://www.mahindraverito.com/everito/pdf/everito_brochure.pdf) on page three & four

72V battery pack

and

Usable capacity of 266 Ah

How do I find the energy density of the battery?

Comment: Which physical quantities are needed to calculate energy density and which do you have?

Comment: I wanted to know the energy density of the battery used in this vehicle called `Mahindra E-Verito` I don't have any details more than what I just mentioned

Comment: I know you do. I’m asking a leading question what you need to calculate it and what you have. Please state both.

Comment: How are you going to use any result? What will you compare it to?

Comment: Ah per kg? Ah per m^3?

Comment: I would like to know in `Watt hours/Kg`

Comment: Not able to find technical details as mentioned in the article [Tesla Model 3 2170 Energy Density Compared To Bolt, Model S P100D](https://insideevs.com/news/342679/tesla-model-3-2170-energy-density-compared-to-bolt-model-s-p100d/)

Comment: You need to know the weight of the battery.

Comment: You don't know the weight so it can't be done. Best you can do is find the total energy, which is a simple multiplication. If you also know the battery *chemistry* you can approximate it by calculating the energy density of similar (but more fully specified) batteries.

Comment: _”I would like to know in Watt hours/Kg”_ Finally, three physical quantities. How many of the three do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you’re asking for either kWh/kg or kWh/m^3.  We know the energy stored in the battery but not the volume or weight.  Without this neither question can be answered.

Comment: Somebody's downvote for a correct answer is regrettable, but probably inevitable for such a poor question.

Comment: @user_1818839 is there an answer? This is a comment.

Comment: At a philosophical level there can be no answer to an unanswerable question, but from a practical viewpoint it's better to explain why the question is unanswerable than to say nothing.  Anyhoo the OP seems to have got the message.